# Fetch custom response post request

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core

I am logging a user in the system by sending data through a FormData() to the action in the backend. The user logs in, everything is fine. I want to send back to the frontend a response (string, Json) doesn't matter.

```
[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

    var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return new JsonResult("Succeeded", new JsonSerializerSettings());
        // or return new[] { user.DisplayName, user.Role };
    }

    return new JsonResult("Failed", new JsonSerializerSettings());
    //return Content("Failed");
}
```

On the frontend I expect to see the passed string or json, but I get this as a response from fetch.

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://ip/api/sampledata/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "https://ip/api/sampledata/login"
```

Answer (score 0):

.net core you dont want to return JsonResults.

read below article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

       var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok(user); // your object
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: After I use the Ok method, where should I see the string or object, because the response on the frontend is the same

Comment: @Andrea you should see the string in your response body

Comment: return ok will provide 200 statecode and json result. I think your frontend code has to change. Use postman to test your api before integrate with frontend

Comment: select type to post and put url with parameters. click send, you will see the response

Comment: @cdev I can see in the Network Tab after the login request in Preview the response , it is correct

Comment: sorry i cant understand the problem now. what is the issue now?